# How to improve Firefox 75 fonts on Fedora Linux?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, firefox, fedora, fonts

I'm trying to switch from Chrome to Firefox on Fedora Linux. Text looks better in Chrome, more readable. Here's an example with
https://news.ycombinator.com/ at 110% font zoom:

[image]

Firefox, on the left, looks wider and has less spacing between each news item.

Solutions I've already tried from other answers:

- installing ttf-ubuntu-fonts on Fedora
- preferences on the about:config page

```
layers.acceleration.force-enabled > true
layers.acceleration.disabled > false
gfx.xrender.enabled > false
```

Is Chrome using it's own fonts, as per this screenshot from Chrome settings?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem and I believe I solved it finally.

Create a file in /etc/fonts/local.conf with something similar to this. The key is the subpixel lcdfilter which is very important for these ClearType fonts.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
       <alias binding="same">
         <family>Helvetica</family>
         <accept>
         <family>Arial</family>
         </accept>
       </alias>
       <alias binding="same">
         <family>Times</family>
         <accept>
         <family>Times New Roman</family>
         </accept>
       </alias>
       <alias binding="same">
         <family>Courier</family>
         <accept>
         <family>Courier New</family>
         </accept>
       </alias>
       <match target="font">
    <edit name="lcdfilter" mode="assign">
      <const>lcddefault</const>
    </edit>
  </match>
</fontconfig>
```

All of those strange artifacts are now gone.